# What command will tell me what version of Ubuntu I'm running?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, linux-distributions

I'm looking for a Unix/Linux command to determine what version of what distro I'm running.

**Specifically, I want to be able distinguish between Ubuntu 9.04 and 9.10.**

I was thinking something along the lines of `uname -a`, but that didn't work.

Ubuntu 9.04 gives:

```
Linux myhost 2.6.28-17-generic #58-Ubuntu SMP Tue Dec 1 21:27:25 UTC 2009 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Ubuntu 9.10 gives:

```
Linux myhost 2.6.31-17-generic #54-Ubuntu SMP Thu Dec 10 17:01:44 UTC 2009 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use this,

```
cat /etc/issue
```

or this,

```
cat /etc/lsb-release
```

The latter is probably better since it also gives the release name such as "karmic", etc. But it depends what you're using it for I guess.

Comment: +1 /etc/issue works both on Debian and Ubuntu.

Answer (score 5):

`lsb_release` also displays the version:

```
$ lsb_release -a
```

> No LSB modules are available.
>
> Distributor ID: Ubuntu
>
> Description: Ubuntu feisty(
>   development branch)
>
> Release: 7.04
>
> Codename: feisty